# How to record browser content into a video?

Tags: video, browser

How can I record what a browser renders into a video?

I would like to create an Animation/Illustration Video using HTML, CSS and Javascript. However, I would like to render what is happening in the the browser into a Video (mp4, avi, mkv, ...) with a constant frame rate (e.g. 30), but only the content area, not the whole desktop nor the browsers menu/scroll bars.

Audio is not a concern here. Also, the animation is not interactive.

What is the easiest way to do that? Is there a command line tool that can render a dynamic page frame by frame into a set of images, ideally I can specify the timewindow I would like to render (e.g. from 00:01:23 to 00:03:45)? Using a screen/window capture tool and a fullscreen-browser and a video cutting tool?

Ideally, the solution works in Linux, but other OSes are fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I set the screen resolution to 1920x1080 on a Ubuntu machine, used a fullscreen Firefox (F11-key) to display the animation, and used a custom built ffmpeg to record the whole screen.